Pausing Windows Tamper Protection and Defender - not possible anymore
I have Windows 11 23H2. I have logged in with my office 365 account. I suddenly faced problem that I cannot pause defender temporarily. Defender is suddenly managed by tamper protection. Tamper protection is managed by administrator. Problem is that I should be an administrator. I have always been and i have no other accounts and licenses in my organization.

When i go to powershell as admin and type
Set-MpPreference -DisableTamperProtection $true


I get error: You don't have enough permissions to perform the requested operation.

When I log in to https://security.microsoft.com/ I see no settings for tamper protection at all.

I have global admin role in https://admin.microsoft.com/

When i go to https://endpoint.microsoft.com/ and go to endpoint security i see "Unauthorized" page https://intune.microsoft.com/ goes to same site.

When i try to file a suppor ticket i get "



You are currently signed in with an Azure Active Directory account.
Professional support packages must be purchased using a Microsoft
account. For more information on this process, click here


and when i Click here. I get


"Professional Support (pay-per-incident) support plans are not
available for Microsoft Entra ID accounts" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/sfbus/support-for-business/professional-support-aad)


Registry editor Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender ManagedDefenderProductType is Zero (0)

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features (or HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features TamperProtection is 5 and i cannot change it


I'm really frustrated how i cannot have full control of my windows anymore. What should I do?  (Suddenly came another problem where Windows Subsystem for Linux stopped working but that is an another case).
I appreciate any help!

From what you wrote, this isn’t an “Office 365” account but an Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory) account. Sounds like your computer isn’t actually your computer but your organization’s computer.

Might be, i purchased this and logged in. But anyhow where i can modify settings that i have full control :/

What is the ACL on Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features, I would not expect an Administrator to necessarily have access to the entire HKLM hive. This has nothing to do with you running 23H2 I am finding individuals with this exact problem from 2020. I suspect the reason WSL is not working is connected. If you solve that problem this problem will be solved.

Administrators has only Read access and full control cannot be set :/ "Access Denied"
